# Inclusion of values that can only be zero in Poisson glmer

Tags: generalized-linear-model, biostatistics, glmm, zero-inflation, offset

I have carried out a biological experiment in which the dependent variable is female propensity to mating, measured as the number of times a female animal accepts a mating attempt from a male.

I have modelled this as a poisson generalised mixed effects model, with number of accepts as the dependent variable, and an offset of the number of times a female was approached. I've excluded from this any females that weren't approached at all (a substantial proportion), as there is no way they can have anything other than zero accepts.

My supervisor thinks that these females who weren't approached at all must be included, possibly as part of a hurdle model. However, I think that using an offset means inclusion should have little or no effect on the model, and any effect it did have would be adding unnecessary uncertainty. I would be very grateful for any perspectives on this.